# Timeline for adding Oauth2 support for IMAP

Tags: exchange-basicauth

In [this](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/end-of-support-for-basic-authentication-access-to-exchange-online-apis-for-office-365-customers/) blog post it is mentioned that basic auth support for IMAP would be removed in October 2020. It also mentions Oauth2 support will be introduced soon. Could you provide any timeline for Oauth2 support?

In our product for a use case, we rely on IMAP to sync a specified mailbox . We are using IMAP with basic auth now.  Will Oauth2 support be released before Oct 2020. Is there any beta program to which we can sign up, so that we can make the required changes and test.

Comment: Any update regarding this?

Comment: As far as I understand the blog post states that they will not change SMTP AUTH and that they will continue to support Basic Authentication for Exchange Online.

Comment: @Alex SMTP is for *sending* emails. IMAP is for *receiving* and *managing* emails. Two different protocols. The OP is asking about IMAP, which is affected by Microsoft's change.

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes, you are right of course! I must have misunderstood something back then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft have now released support for IMAP OAuth support. See “ [Authenticate an IMAP, POP or SMTP connection using OAuth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth)” for details.